# Sea level change layer

Tags: data, sea-level-rise

Is there a vector layer showing sea level change by different cities around the world (so not just US or just EU ones)? I remember looking at ArcGIS Webmap some time ago, but can't find it now anymore. I would definitely prefer vector data as I would be able to have cities listed in the table, over raster data where I would need to manually look up for approximate number of each city.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check [PSMSL data](https://www.psmsl.org/data/) to have a global overview of the sea-level.
You can compare means over a year to get a idea of the changes.
[Here](https://www.gloss-sealevel.org/mean-sea-level-data-delivery) is the status of the Sea Level Network.

The NASA platform can be a good way to find those data. [Here](https://sealevel.nasa.gov/data/dataset/?identifier=SLCP_MERGED_TP_J1_OSTM_OST_GMSL_ASCII_V42_4.2)

Answer (score 1):

I found this paper today: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-12808-z and here you have two webs: https://coast.noaa.gov/slrdata/ and https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/sod/lsa/SeaLevelRise/LSA_SLR_timeseries.php